How is the IDF taking over the Philadelphi Corridor a violation of the Israel-Egypt peace treaty?
From news earlier this year:

Diaa Rashwan, head of the Egypt’s official public relations office, the State Information Service (SIS), issued a stern warning that any “occupation” of the Philadelphi Corridor by Israeli forces would be a violation of the 1978 peace treaty between the two neighbouring nations.

However, looking just at the Wikipedia summary of the treaty, the main provision appears to have been that Egypt had to demilitarize Sinai, but Israel doesn't appear to have been obligated to demilitarize anything (in return). (N.B. Egypt got Sinai back in return, as it was occupied by the IDF at the time.)
So, how is the IDF taking over the Philadelphi Corridor remotely a violation of the peace treaty between Israel and Egypt?

To be fair, even if it runs against the treaty, no one besides Hamas wants a redo of 10/7, so the world will have to find a way to keep Gaza more demilitarized, whatever statehood status Gaza ends up with.  Whether or not the Egypt border was the main arms conduit I dunno, but if it was it will have to be secured, somehow because something didn't work with the previous arrangements.

A slight clarification, the document referred to in  the answer I accepted is a

Letter Agreement, additional to the above-mentioned Treaty, concerning the establishment of full autonomy in the West Bank and the Gaza Strip

Technically speaking, it's not part of the peace treaty, but I suppose Egypt might not have signed it otherwise. The letter itself starts on page 23 of this pdf, after the annexes to the treaty proper.
However, reading more closely the wording of this letter, one might argue it's a closer to "political declaration" than to a treaty, because it's mostly about intentions rather than hard promises, which seem limited to start negotiations. For example it says:

For the purpose of achieving a comprehensive peace settlement in accordance with the above-mentioned Frameworks, Egypt and Israel will proceed with
the implementation of those provisions relating to the West Bank and the Gaza
Strip. They have agreed to start negotiations within a month after the exchange of
the instruments of ratification of the Peace Treaty. In accordance with the
"Framework for Peace in the Middle East", the Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan
is invited to join the negotiations. The Delegations of Egypt and Jordan may include Palestinians from the West Bank and Gaza Strip or other Palestinians as mutually agreed. The purpose of the negotiation shall be to agree, prior to the elections, on the modalities for establishing the elected self-governing authority (administrative council), define its powers and responsibilities, and agree upon other related issues. In the event Jordan decides not to take part in the negotiations, the negotiations will be held by Egypt and Israel.
The two Governments agree to negotiate continuously and in good faith to
conclude these negotiations at the earliest possible date. They also agree that the
objective of the negotiations is the establishment of the self-governing authority
in the West Bank and Gaza in order to provide full autonomy to the inhabitants.

I suppose that one can argue that "full autonomy" excludes IDF presence from those territories, but it isn't exactly put in explicit terms like that in the letter. Plenty of regions in other countries have something that is called autonomy, but that doesn't exclude armed presence of encompassing state. Of course, that's predicated as "full autonomy" in the letter in question, however I suppose there can be room for argument what that means, i.e. where's the difference between that (or "self-governing authority") and [outright] independence.

One slightly more obscure point. Around p. 29 in that pdf collection of documents is there is this:

In the area within 3 km east of the international border there will be Israeli
limited military forces not to exceed four infantry battalions and United Nations observers.

However, that is part of the "FRAMEWORK FOR THE CONCLUSION OF A PEACE TREATY BETWEEN EGYPT AND ISRAEL", which however appears to have been superseded by the treaty proper. The latter has a provision that "This Treaty supersedes the Agreement between Egypt and Israel of September, 1975." But the "FRAMEWORK FOR THE CONCLUSION [...]" is undated in that collection, so I'm not sure if that's [also] being superseded or not.
A bit more searching elsewhere finds that that "FRAMEWORK FOR THE CONCLUSION [...]" was actually dated 1978, so I think that's also still technically in force (albeit distinct from the [1979] Treaty proper, as well.)
N.B. this provision appears to have been incorporated in the treaty proper as well. (The somewhat stilted expression "Israeli limited force" made it easy to find its correspondent in the Treaty proper.) However in the latter it's been reframed with respect to some Zone D on a map, and spells out the composition of the forces allowed there in more detail:

Zone D is bounded by line D (blue line) on the east and the international boundary on the west, as shown on Map 1. In this Zone there will be an Israeli limited force of four infantry battalions, their military installations, and field fortifications, and United Nations observers. The Israeli forces in Zone D will not include tanks, artillery and anti-aircraft missiles except individual surface-to-air missiles. The main elements of the four Israeli infantry battalions will consist of up to 180 armored personnel vehicles of all types and up to a total of four thousand personnel. Access across the international boundary shall only be permitted through entry check points designated by each Party and under its control. Such access shall be in accordance with laws and regulations of each country. Only those field fortifications, military installations, forces, and weapons specifically permitted by this Annex shall be in the Zones.

So, if "Zone D" includes the Philadelphi corridor, Israel is not supposed to have (proper) tanks there, but can have 180 "armored personnel vehicles" (and 4,000 personnel) thereabout.
Now the map is alas quite poorly reproduced in that pdf, but it does look like Zone D is more or less that strip within 3 km of the border textually described in the earlier Framework that preceded the treaty.

But you can see that the map only partly shows Gaza, so it's still somewhat unclear to me if Zone D includes all the border of Gaza with Egypt. (N.B. that poor [map] reproduction is alas what's [also] included in UN's treaty database. To add somewhat to the confusion, the IDF color version of that map seems not to show "Zone D" at all on the map itself, although it appears in the map's legend.)
The MFO manages to have a more legible map, at least as far as the Zone D exact limits goes, which does extend into Gaza. (There no UN troops eventually, which are [also] indicated on that map, because the USSR threatened to veto that. So the MFO replaced those.)


Now since I did look at this treaty and its maps in some detail, the presence of Egyptian tanks [and even APCs] on the other side of Rafah [something that also happened] is technically not permitted either, due to treaty provisions for Zone C. Only "Egyptian civil police [...] armed with light weapons" is allowed there. (They're also allowed "unarmed police helicopters".) I suppose due to the Sinai insurgency Israel gave some kind of [tacit perhaps] permission to the Egyptians to exceed those limits, even before 2023.

Around 2012, Egypt deploying tanks to Sinai apparently did elicit some Israeli objections.
